# How fast extract db file from Android device?

Tags: android, realm, adb

In my Android project I use Realm.
Sometimes I need to extract db file from device. 
To do this I follow the next steps:

1. Open console
2. adb shell
3. run-as my_project_name_space
4. cd files
5. cp my_db_file.realm /sdcard
6. exit
7. exit
8. adb pull sdcard/my_db_file.realm d:\Temp\my_db_file.realm

As result in folder `d:\Temp` I get db file: `my_db_file.realm`

Nice. It's work fine.
But when I need again to extract db file I must again do all of this 8 steps.
Has any faster approach?
Something like start script that execute all of this 8 steps. Or or something similar.

Thanks.

Comment: You could write a shell script that takes project name and DB file name as parameters.

Answer (score 1):

In debug apk you can use android studio's device explorer 

 goto path
/data/data/your-package-name/files/your-db.realm
and by right clicking you can save it without running any kind of code.